# Do you know a free Lookup control for MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, lookup

I would like to include into my project a lookup control. Example of this control [here](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=1081) :

But I'm a simple student, and so I'm very poor :)

So do you know a free control like this for my mvc3 project ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Downvoter - Why isn't this a good question? Is it a dupe?

Comment: I was one of the downvoters.  It is not a good question because it does not show research effort - searching for the words "lookup control" gives results which are ALL free autocomplete controls.  Also, it is not a good question because it is unclear - the term is non-standard, so the example provided is a key part of the question but the example was a whole search engine with an ASP.NET control.  Clarity and research effort are the two main criteria for voting, duplicates should not be downvoted, they should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is the jQuery UI "Autocomplete" plugin:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

This doesn't integrate with MVC out of the box; you'd need to write a server side method to provide the content for the completion drop down.

Comment: Hmm, interesting I didn't know it... Thanks

Comment: The control you linked to in the question is a search engine.  If you want a search engine with an autocomplete ui, you need the actual search engine first.

Comment: @ColinPickard The OP didn't want a search engine, he wanted a "lookup control". He did not specify what he wanted to lookup, nor did he ask how to write a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Google! Many sites embeds external search engines.

Comment: Sorry but I have make some research but many control like this are very expensive and not free

Comment: He doesn't mean you should research your answer, he means you can embed a Google custom search into your site e.g. http://www.google.co.uk/cse/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to add a search engine to your web site, there are three things you need to thing about:

1. The index, which holds the search results.  Lucene, Solr and Sphinx are examples of this.
2. The crawler, which gathers the results and puts them into the index
3. The ui to get the results back from the index.

The control you linked to seems to provide all three. For a free replacement, maybe have a look at something like http://www.searchblox.com/